# How do I use SVN URLs as dependencies with npm?

Tags: svn, npm, package-managers, yarnpkg

I would like to use an SVN repository URL as a dependency for my project. I know that it is possible with a Git repository. According to [this documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies), with something like `git+https://user@hostname/project/blah.git#commit-ish`, we can use a Git repository as npm dependency.

I also know that it is possible using Bower, but I would like to use only npm (or Yarn, meaning only one `package.json`).

Comment: AFAIK npm doesn't support it natively. Have you looked at the `npm-svn` package?